# Sparse Matrix inversion without actual inversion

Tags: complexity-theory, matrices, linear-algebra, numerical-analysis, sparse-matrices

I want to know what are the efficient way to invert a Sparse Matrix? Are there any algorithm,linear algebra or expansions that make this task easier with out actually inverting the matrix?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to calculate an inverse of a sparse matrix, or do you want to solve a sparse linear system?

Comment: The equation I want to solve is  **mu*omega=Xi** Now, omega and Xi is known term for me. I have to find out mu. So,the equation will be **mu=omega.inverse().Xi** . Now how could I solve it?

Comment: Do you mean **mu=Xi$\cdot$(omega.inverse())**, since matrix multiplication is not commutative in general?

Comment: No. I mean **mu=(omega.inverse()).Xi**

Comment: So, I guess **(omega.inverse()).Xi = Xi * (omega.inverse())**? If so, this usage of dot before the first Xi looks like unconventional to me. Are you using a particular kind of software package?